# Failed dependencies errors while installing MySQL on CentOS Linux

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

I am trying to install MySQL on Linux. And it seems that I'm confused which MySQL package I should use for my particular Linux environment.

My Linux Details:

```
Linux 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 20 03:51:51 BST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final)
```

So I went for MySQL package `MySQL-server-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64.rpm` (download from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql#downloads)). I choose `Linux-Generic` from dropdown. But when I try to install it I got this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libaio.so.1()(64bit) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
    libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
    libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.x86_64
```

I got more failed dependencies errors when I choose `MySQL-server-5.5.20-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm`. So both are not working.

Comment: Which distribution do you use ?

Comment: If it's something from RH or CentOS you should use yum to install packages it will resolve your dependencies.

Comment: Tell your distro

Comment: its CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final).

Comment: Ok i used yum to install. After installation when i issue `mysql` command i got this error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'`

Comment: it means it hasnt started it's another question. did you create the database? did you start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
yum install mysql-server
```

Then start it by trying one of these:

```
/sbin/service mysql start
/sbin/service mysqld start
```

Comment: Ok i used yum to install. After installation when i issue mysql command i got this error ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Comment: Did you start the server after installing it ? `/sbin/service mysql start` , or `/sbin/service mysqld start`

Answer (score 7):

After a similar error, I figured out what your problem was (and had a big "durrrr" on my side, as I was building from SRPM in the background):

When using the packages from mysql.com, be certain that you're downloading the correct version for your platform (32-bit or 64-bit), including all of the supplemental packages.  <strike>MySQL</strike> Oracle has a terrible webpage layout, and it's easy to mix things up.

To install the dependency for either architecture:

```
yum install libaio
```

or if you need 32-bit MySQL on the 64-bit architecture:

```
yum install libaio.686
```

You could always install the in-distro packages (as discussed above), but this is a direct response to your original issue.  I think it's pretty easy to mix up downloads on that site.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.x or a CentOS 6.x. (the "el6" in your kernel id).

Please try to get the rpm for you own distrib from either redhat.com or centos.org (they are more or less compatible which each other).
I would recommend you use the "yum" installation tool, which will solve all the dependencies itself:

```
yum install mysql-server
```

Answer (score -2):

Start the MySQL service either by using

```
service mysqld start
```

or

```
/usr/bin/mysqld start
```